# How to prevent function from modifying list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The list that I pass to the function as "puzzle" is being modified, and I want the function to keep it the same.

```
"""moveDown() works by swapping the empty space with the block above it."""
def moveDown(xPosition, yPosition, puzzle):
    returnPuzzle = list()
    returnPuzzle.append(puzzle)
    returnPuzzle = returnPuzzle[0]

    if(puzzle[yPosition][xPosition]!=0):  # is space we are moving the block into not empty?
        return -1
    if(yPosition-1<0):
        return -1

    print puzzle
    #swap
    returnPuzzle[yPosition][xPosition] = returnPuzzle[yPosition-1][xPosition]
    returnPuzzle[yPosition-1][xPosition]   = 0
    print puzzle

    return returnPuzzle
```

The first `print` statement returns the original `puzzle` that was passed to the function, but the second has modified it as though it was working on `returnPuzzle` instead of `puzzle`. Any idea why?

First print: `[[2, 1, 3], [6, 4, 5], [8, 7, 0]]`

Second print: `[[2, 1, 3], [6, 4, 0], [8, 7, 5]]`

Comment: Can you provide an input example?

Comment: moveDown(2, 2, [[2, 1, 3], [6, 4, 5], [8, 7, 0]]) is what is being used right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answers have stated, you're just assigning `puzzle` to `returnPuzzle`. Because it's a nested list, you need to make what's called a "deep copy"; the other answers are referring to a shallow copy, where you copy the list but the items in the list are still the same. That means that you end up with a new outer list containing the same inner lists. Since you're mutating the inner lists, you want a copy of those as well.

The easiest way to do this is with the `copy` module:

```
import copy
def moveDown(xPosition, yPosition, puzzle):
    returnPuzzle = copy.deepcopy(puzzle)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
returnPuzzle = list()
returnPuzzle.append(puzzle)
returnPuzzle = returnPuzzle[0]
```

So you create a list, append a value to it, and then retrieve that value from the list - this has NO effect whatsoever, it's exactly the same thing as accessing `puzzle` directly.  To make a copy that you can modify without affecting the original list, use:

```
returnPuzzle = puzzle[:]
```

(that's a list slice, using the default values of the start and end of the list.)

Comment: That's only a shallow copy, though, and it looks like we need something at least one level deeper.

Comment: I tried using the code you suggested, unfortunately it still didn't work. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Since `puzzle` is a 2d list, you need to construct a copy of it to avoid references to the inner list being kept during the copy.

```
def duplicate2dList(oldList):
    newList = []

    for l in oldList:
        newList.append(l[:])

    return newList
```